# My question is about Independent events of the following question in which tree diagram is said to make. How to do this?

Tags: probability

Suppose identical tags are placed on both the left ear and the right
ear of a fox. The fox is then let loose for a period of time.
Consider the two events $C_1 = \{\text{left ear tag is lost}\}$ and $C_2 = \{\text{right ear tag is lost}\}$. Let $\pi = P(C_1) = P(C_2)$, and assume $C_1$ and $C_2$
are independent events. Derive an expression (involving $\pi$) for the
probability that exactly one tag is lost given that at most one is
lost.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the event where exactly one tag is lost and $B$ be the event where at most one tag is lost. Then we are looking for
$$
P(A\mid B).
$$
By the definition of conditional probability,
$$
P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}.
$$
If exactly one tag is lost, then it's true that at most one tag is lost, so $A\subset B$. Hence $P(A\cap B) = P(A)$. Hence we have to compute
$$
P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A)}{P(B)}.
$$
The probability $P(A)$ that exactly one event of $C_1,C_2$ happens is given by
\begin{align*}
P(A) &= P(C_1) + P(C_2) - 2\cdot P(C_1\cap C_2) \\
&= \pi + \pi - 2\pi^2 = 2\pi(1-\pi).
\end{align*}
We used the identity $P(C_1\cap C_2) = P(C_1)\cdot P(C_2)$ because the events $C_1,C_2$ are independent.

The probability $P(B)$ that at most one tag is lost is $1-P(B^c)$, where $P(B^c)$ is the probability $P(C_1\cap C_2)$ that both tags are lost. Hence,
$$
P(B) = 1 - P(B^c) = 1 - P(C_1\cap C_2) = 1 - \pi^2 = (1-\pi)(1+\pi).
$$
Putting it all together,
$$
P(A\mid B) = \frac{2\pi(1-\pi)}{(1-\pi)(1+\pi)} = \color{blue}{\frac{2\pi}{1+\pi}}.
$$